# Have .bat ask for further input

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

If I end a line in cmd with `^`, it will ask for more input.

```
D:\some\folders>do ^
More? stuff
```

Let's say I don't want to enter `do` every time I wanna do stuff so I put it in a .bat, and let's say the `stuff` I want to do varies each time. So I create the following .bat file:

```
do ^
```

and I run it and expect it to ask for `More?` so I can enter my `stuff`. But it doesn't. It does nothing for all eternity. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `^` character is the batch file ["escape" character](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).  When used by itself at the end of a line, it becomes a [line-continuation character](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/myocom/2005/09/30/making-your-scripts-look-prettier/), used for treating multiple lines as a single line.

So, in a batch file, if you put in

```
echo This ^
is a single ^
line!
```

It treats it as a single line, equivalent to:

```
echo This is a single line!
```

If there is no "next line" in the batch, like in your single line batch example of `do ^`, there's no next line to append, so it doesn't append anything (and therefore appears to do nothing).

When you use the `^` line-continuation at a command prompt, it will show you the `More?` prompt because you told it you want to continue the command on the next line, at which point you can continue the command, e.g.:

```
Y:\>echo This ^
More? is a single ^
More? line!
This is a single line!
```

To have a batch file stop and prompt for input, you would want to look into using `set /p`, which will prompt for input and then assign that input to a variable.  e.g.:

```
set /P name="What Is Your Name? "
echo Hello %name%!
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want a batch to prompt you for input you're going to use set /p.  For example to create a variable %stuff% you can use in the batch the command would look like this.

```
set /p stuff=What stuff do you want to do?:
```

This will put the prompt "What stuff do you want to do?" and you can enter the stuff, this will then be in the %stuff% variable you can use elsewhere in your script.